# Drupal7: Some of the main Menu links not showing if not logged in

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-navigation, drupal-menu

I have created a Main Menu with 4 main links. This is visible if i am logged in but only the ''Our Company'' is showing if i log out. Could anybody help me on this issue?

**logged in:**[image]

**logged out:**
[image]

Comment: I think the links provided in the menu are not able to access by the anonymous user. Kindly give permission to the anonymous user role to access the page

Comment: how to do that ? @PraveenKumar

Comment: is it views page or content type?

Comment: You have to go on `/admin/people/permissions/roles` and administer anonymous permissions to auhtorize access on content type of node 'Our company'

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 automatically hides menu items that the user does not have access to.

**1. Ensure that the page you've added to the menu is published.**
Edit the nodes missing from the menu, and at the bottom you should see Publishing Options where you can set the page as published.

**2. Ensure that the Content Type you're using for the missing pages has Read Access for anon.**
Go to www.example.com/admin/people/permissions/1 for all Anon permissions.

If neither option helps, please tell us if an anon user can access the pages directly, by URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this module in your site. https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_per_role

you will get different roles inside the links when you can change it's visibility options as per your need.

Thanks!